# "Costs a pretty penny"

Tags: idioms

I have read "costs a pretty penny" before.

Is it okay if I instead use "costs a pretty dollar" or "costs a pretty yen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can say anything you want, but the more remote or non-standard it is, the less likely you'll be understood. I guess that's almost too obvious to say. However, if you said *costs a pretty dollar*, you might get an askance look from people :-).

*Pretty penny* is an older colloquialism. Old enough that it is trite.

If you said that costs a pretty yen to me, I'd ask you "well how are things in Japan these days?" :))

Answer (score 3):

*Pretty penny* is a fixed phrase.  The relevant sense of *pretty* is now listed as "archaic or dialectal" in the OED:

> Considerable in number, quantity, or extent, as in ***a pretty deal, while, way,*** etc.
>   . . .
>   Now *arch.* or *dial.*

We still use it with this meaning as an **adverb**, but not as an **adjective**.  We say a movie was *pretty good*, but we don't talk about having <sup>#</sup>*a pretty dollar*.

The relevant meaning of *penny* is now obscure.  It doesn't refer to **a single physical penny**; instead, it represents **a sum of money** more generally.  The relevant sense from the OED:

> Used as a general or vague word for a piece of money; hence, a sum of money, money.   Now chiefly in [the phrase] ***a pretty penny*** . . .

Combine these two senses, and you get a phrase *pretty penny* meaning **a considerable sum of money**.

However, speakers of today's English don't understand these senses of *pretty* or *penny*.  We don't think of the phrase *pretty penny* this way.  Instead, we treat the entire phrase as a single vocabulary item with a fixed meaning.  Because this is true, you can't build similar phrases using these senses of *pretty* or *penny*.  And as a result, your examples sound at best like wordplay.  At worst, they won't be understood at all.

---

In this answer, the <sup>#</sup> symbol means that the utterance, while not *ungrammatical*, fails to express the intended meaning.

Comment: Is _penny/pennies_ ever used to refer to a fraction of dollar? I remember that a friend of mine (American) used one of those words. I objected that she has cents, but she didn't reply me. I think she was telling how to call the different fractions of a dollar, and said "[…], a dime, 5 pennies, […]."

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think *four pennies* refers to four physical coins, and *four cents* refers to the value of those pennies.  So it would sound strange to say I have *four pennies* in my bank account, but I could say I have *four pennies* in my pocket.  And if I were describing those five coins, I'd say either "a dime and four pennies" or "14 cents".  I think "a dime and 4 cents" sounds wrong.